# GraphView library remove series

Tags: android, android-graphview

I have been using the Graphview library, and its working great for my simple graphs. But there isnt really much information on this library, and i was wondering how i can remove a series.

I am refreshing the data from at spinner but they just add a new line at the graph, so i gotta clear it first.

I did search a lot, and try a lot, but found nothing.

Preferably i would like a clear all series function, so i dont have to put the series into variables.

The only information i could find about the library is here http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html

I know that this code will make the function, but is it possible to add it to a packed library, and how?

```
  public boolean removeSeries(GraphViewSeries series) {
boolean result;
result = false;
if (graphSeries.contains(series)) {
graphSeries.remove(series);
result = true;
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: how is this work i'did not get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A removeSeries method was added a few days ago, in this pull request: https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/pull/6